# Deploying WSGI Application - Apache and/or Nginx

Tags: apache, nginx, wsgi

I've just recently started working with Python WSGI based frameworks (Pyramid and Flask).
I've been working with Apache since forever, but recently I got a lot hype for asynchronous non-blocking event-based technologies like node.js and Nginx.

So I've decided, that when my application goes into production, its going to run in virtual cloud server on Nginx and its going to be super, duper fast...but than I thought...wait a second...wsgi application is a BLOCKING application by design. So wouldn't a wsgi application actually run worse on Nginx than Apache, since it would block the process and jam the server right away? Probably Apache is much better than for my application with its multi-threading.

Anyway, now I am trying to figure out what am I going to use in production, so I can prepare and optimize in that way. I am pretty much a newbie on this field, so I've got some ideas, but Im not sure what route to take.

```
1.) Have nginx serve my wsgi app, but create some kind of load balancer that sends requests to various nginx instances, as running single process would probably fail miserably as my python app would be blocking it. So I would have 4-8 nginx's running.
2.) Have apache serve everything, wsgi+static
3.) Have apache serve the app via mod_wsgi, and nginx serve static files
4.) Any other solutions?
```

I am looking for a best equilibrium between performance, resource usage, reliability and convenience. I do not believe that either nginx or apache would be a bottleneck for my app if configured correctly.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have yet to find a straight forward way to deploy nginx + wsgi.  Everyone says use Gunicorn and there are some procedures to be found.  However I was only able to find one procedure that shows how to start Gunicorn on boot and run as a background process and it was complicated. Required installing supervisor and creating custom script to run Gunicorn as recommended which is as a socket rather than a daemon. Everything else just shows how to run Gunicorn from command line which is useless for anything besides development.

I was quite surprised considering how everyone was recommending Gunicorn and yet there is no straight forward way to set up start on boot and run in the background.

I ended up using Apache + mod_wsgi which is much easier to install and just works.  Forget about using nginx + wsgi imho.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say how you intend running the WSGI application with nginx. If you are looking at the ngx_wsgi_module then don't, as it will introduce blocking issues due to running inside of nginx process. See:

- http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2009/05/blocking-requests-and-nginx-version-of.html

If you are talking about using nginx more as a proxy through to a WSGI application running as FASTCGI, SCGI, with uWSGI, or even under gunicorn as a backend, then you are fine as although nginx will block for the specific request while waiting for the WSGI application, it has a high capacity to handle concurrent requests when proxying due to its asynchronous design.

Comment: yeah I really don't wanna do wsgi on nginx. What if I use nginx just as proxy for apache, and run app via apache thru wsgi?

Comment: Go watch my talk where I talk in part about these issues. http://lanyrd.com/2012/pycon/spcdg/

Answer (score 0):

You should consider setting them both up and run some benchmarks to see which runs best with your application.

Either Apache or Nginx can be beneficial, depending on your resource needs and how your application handles connections.